Cycle inside cycle AlpineJS
Im new in alpineJS. I read official documentation and google, but I have not found any answer to the question: how to loop through nested array? Example:
<body>
    <div x-data="comments()">
        <template x-for="i in commentsList">
            <p x-text="i.text"></p>
            <template x-for="reply in i.replies">
                <p x-text="reply.text"></p>
            </template>
        </template>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    const comments = () => {
        return {
            commentsList: [
                {
                    "createdAt": "20.01",
                    "text": "Hello all how can i use double cycle in alpinejs?",
                    "replies": [
                        {
                            "createdAt": "21.01",
                            "text": "I dont know?"
                        },
                        {
                            "createdAt": "22.01",
                            "text": "What is written in official doc?"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "createdAt": "23.01",
                    "text": "How to show replies?",
                    "replies": [
                        {
                            "createdAt": "24.01",
                            "text": "It is not possible right now"
                        }
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
    }
</script>

I read official documentation and used google. I need to get the answer to question, because I have not found it.

I found the answer: x-for body should be wrapped in any tag like div. Example:
<div x-data="comments()">
    <template x-for="comment in commentsList">
        <div>
            <p x-text="comment.text"></p>
            <template x-for="reply in comment.replies">
                <div>
                    <p x-text="reply.createdAt"></p>
                    <p x-text="reply.text"></p>
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
<script>
    const comments = () => {
        return {
            commentsList: [
                {
                    "createdAt": "20.01",
                    "text": "Hello all how can i use double cycle in alpinejs?",
                    "replies": [
                        {
                            "createdAt": "21.01",
                            "text": "I dont know?"
                        },
                        {
                            "createdAt": "22.01",
                            "text": "What is written in official doc?"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "createdAt": "23.01",
                    "text": "How to show replies?",
                    "replies": [
                        {
                            "createdAt": "24.01",
                            "text": "It is not possible right now"
                        }
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
    }
</script>

